# Error code 800710dd returned by IPackageManager::SetPackageState on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am trying to check whether my Metro style package is tampered in any way by checking for existence of all the files in the package. If any file is missing, I am setting the package state to `PackageState_Tampered`. But, the API `IPackageManager::SetPackageState` returns `HRESULT 800710dd`. I couldn't find this error code in winerror.h. Seems like it is undocumented. Googling on this error code shows that this occurs only during Windows Update failure.

Any ideas on what could be the reason?

I am using Windows 8 build 8295.

Answer (score 0):

800710dd = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION)

It's a little vague what you're doing. Can you provide code, along with values you're passing to SetPackageState etc?

Answer (score 0):

From [the `PackageManager` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager):

> **Important**  You can't use this class in a Metro style app.